# Selfmade Keyboard show and hide Rad Studio Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

Tags: keyboard, pascal, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I built a cross platform application to run it on Android. I use a TEdit to get the numbers and a Label to show the result of the calculation. 
(This function is already running).

Is there any way to show a calculator keyboard whenever I click into to an TEdit object?

It shouldnt just pop-up like a second form I built in.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`TEdit.KeyboardType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Edit.TCustomEdit.KeyboardType) property to either `TVirtualKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation` or `TVirtualKeyboardType.NumberPad` as needed.  When the user gives focus to the `TEdit`, it will display the OS's standard virtual keyboard in the appropriate layout.